# Junit error - No value present or no such element

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, junit4, junit5

> **testclass.java**

```java
@Test
public void testgetDictionaryValueListById() {

    DictionaryValue dictionaryValue = new DictionaryValue();
    dictionaryValue.setId(1);
    dictionaryValue.setValueName("Test Dictionary Value");
    dictionaryValue.setValueKey("12345678");
    dictionaryValue.setStatus("Active");
    dictionaryValue.setCreatedOn(new Date());
    dictionaryValue.setUpdatedOn(new Date());

    Mockito.when(dictionaryValueRepo.findById(1).get()).thenReturn(dictionaryValue);
    assertThat(dictionaryService.getDictionaryValueListById(1)).isEqualTo(dictionaryValue);

}
```

> **Service.java**

```java
public DictionaryValue getDictionaryValueListById(int id) {
    return dictionaryValueRepo.findById(id).get();
}
```

> **Repo.java**

```java
@Repository
public interface DictionaryValueRepo extends JpaRepository<DictionaryValue, Integer> {

}
```

I am getting no such value present again and again on executing test case in testclass.java. I don't know why? but when I am running my service method from the controller it is working as expected - fetching records from the database but not working in a test case.

Answer (score 1):

Your test should be like this and please check out the naming. You need to Mock the step `findId()` befor the `get().

```
@InjectMocks
Service cut;

@Mock
DictionaryValueRepo dictionaryValueRepoMock;

// Can skipped by adding a @RunWith... on Testclass
@Before
public init() {
    Mockito.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testgetDictionaryValueListById() {

    // Prepare Data
    final int testId = 1;
    DictionaryValue dictionaryValue = new DictionaryValue();
    dictionaryValue.setId(testId);
    dictionaryValue.setValueName("Test Dictionary Value");
    dictionaryValue.setValueKey("12345678");
    dictionaryValue.setStatus("Active");
    dictionaryValue.setCreatedOn(new Date());
    dictionaryValue.setUpdatedOn(new Date());

    // config mocking
    Mockito.when(dictionaryValueRepo.findById(testId)).thenReturn(<VALUE>);
    Mockito.when(dictionaryValueRepo.findById(testId).get()).thenReturn(dictionaryValue);

    // Call yout method for Testing
    cut.getDictionaryValueListById(testId);

    // verifies (if wanted) + assertions....
}
```

Comment: In above, I can't directly call dictionaryValueRepo.findById(testId) because my class is not optional, it will give error. So calling dictionaryValueRepo.findById(testId).get() will give record but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with LenglBoy, so the right answer should be given to him.

The thing you need to be careful is what "VALUE" means in this line:

> Mockito.when(dictionaryValueRepo.findById(testId)).thenReturn(VALUE);

The findById returns an Optional, so that is what you should build and pass to Mockito. Something like this:

```
    Mockito.when(dictionaryValueRepo.findById(testId))
         .thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(dictionaryValue));
```

And for a scenario where the id does not exists in BD, passing Optional.empty() should be good enough.